# how to round multiply in firebird

Tags: rounding, firebird

table:

```
var1 | var2
-----+------
 0.5 | 19.99
```

var1 and var2 is double precision type

I know, that saved value could be 19.9900000000000000000000000001 or 19.989999999999999999999999999999999 (or 0.5 is not exact), but how to get the correct value (If the fractional part is exactly 0.5, rounding is upward for positive numbers and downward for negative numbers. - which comes from [round definition](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-intfunc-round.html)):

```
SELECT var1, var2, round(var1*var2,2), round(0.5*19.99,2), round(9.995,2) FROM table
```

returns

```
var1 |  var2 | this should be 10 | this is 10         | this is also 10
     |       | round(var1*var2,2)| round(0.5*19.99,2) | round(9.995,2) 
-----+-------+-------------------+--------------------+-----------------
 0.5 | 19.99 |      9.99         |      10            |        10
```

I tried round(round(var1,2)*round(var2,2)) but nothing changed

Comment: Note that the literals `0.5` and `19.99` are `DECIMAL(2, 1)` and `DECIMAL(4,2)` respectively (or maybe `NUMERIC`). What is the datatype of `var1` and `var2`? Also it is not entirely clear to what you're asking.

Comment: And also: are you using Firebird or Interbase: they are not the same thing (at least not for the last 18 years).

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what the problem is?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel look at table - this should be 10 but is 9.99

Comment: Compare `select round(0.5 * 19.99, 2), round(cast(0.5 as double precision) * cast(19.99 as double precision), 2) from rdb$database`, most likely cause is that as double precision it is more like 9.99499999999999999999999999 instead, so it rounds down.

Comment: Eg see: `select cast(cast(0.5 as double precision) * cast(19.99 as double precision) as varchar(100)) from rdb$database`

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - I understand the reason, but i need to somehow get 10 instead of 9.99

Answer (score 3):

Literals like `0.5` and `19.99` are `NUMERIC(18, 1)` and `NUMERIC(18, 2)` respectively. The literal `0.5 * 19.99` is a `NUMERIC(18, 3)`, which means the resulting value is exactly 9.995, which when rounded to 2 decimals will result in a `NUMERIC(18, 3)` value of 10.000.

On the other hand the same operations on double precision values are not precise. For example:

```sql
select 
    val1 * val2, 
    cast(val1 * val2 as varchar(100)), 
    round(val1 * val2, 2), 
    round(val1 * val2, 3), 
    round(round(val1 * val2, 3), 2), 
    round(val1 * val2 + 1e-10, 2)
from (
    select 
        cast(0.5 as double precision) as val1, 
        cast(19.99 as double precision) as val2 
    from rdb$database) a
```

Will yield (in flamerobin), respectively:

```
9.995000    9.994999999999999   9.990000    9.995000    10.000000   10.000000
```

Where the first column being 9.995000 is a result of the rendering by flamerobin with max 6 decimals (as shown by the second column).

This may also hint at a solution: first round to a higher number of decimals, and then lower, or add a minor fraction like `1e-10`, however this can still yield incorrect rounding with other values.

The same goes for converting the result to fixed point decimals: you will potentially introduce rounding errors somewhere.

Comment: rounding doesn't work, because if val1=0.3 (0.029999999999999999 to be strict) round(val1,3)= 0.029999999999999999 round(val1,4) 0.029999999999999999. The cast must be done...

Answer (score 0):

the solution for now:

```
SELECT ROUND(CAST(var1 AS DECIMAL(9,2))*CAST(var2 AS DECIMAL(9,2)),2) FROM table
```

but maybe someone has better solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is a good solution:

```
SELECT round(round(val1 * val2, 3), 2) FROM table
```